# How to consume salesforce outbound message and send back the ack using spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, salesforce

Below is the request I am getting from the outbound message

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
 <soapenv:Body>
  <notifications xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2005/09/outbound">
   <OrganizationId>00D740000008gq4EAA</OrganizationId>
   <ActionId>04k74000000CamxAAC</ActionId>
   <SessionId xsi:nil="true"/>
   <EnterpriseUrl>https://test--tdev.sandbox.my.salesforce.com/services/Soap/c/58.0/00D740000008gq4</EnterpriseUrl>
   <PartnerUrl>https://test--tdev.sandbox.my.salesforce.com/services/Soap/u/58.0/00D740000008gq4</PartnerUrl>
   <Notification>
    <Id>04l74000004PScdAAG</Id>
    <sObject xsi:type="sf:Case" xmlns:sf="urn:sobject.enterprise.soap.sforce.com">
     <sf:Id>50074000003Hc2hAAC</sf:Id>
     <sf:CaseNumber>00007664</sf:CaseNumber>
     <sf:LastModifiedDate>2023-07-17T10:22:18.000Z</sf:LastModifiedDate>
     <sf:Status>On Hold</sf:Status>
    </sObject>
   </Notification>
  </notifications>
 </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

I have no idea how to proceed